# Using regex to get a file extension

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

Hi I need a regex that gets the extension of a path, but if it doesnt have an extension it shows nothing or the word "Blank"(<-preferred output)

Here is what I have it works great for paths with extensions but if the path doesnt have an extension I get a full path name showing up when I export to CSV

What I have:
    Extension = $matches.fullname -replace '.*.(.*)','$1'

Example

\Server\ShareFile\RootFolder1.2.3\Folder1.2.3\Subfolder2\Excel.csv

In this case it would get just .csv

\Server\ShareFile\RootFolder1.2.3\Folder1.2.3\Subfolder2\RandomFileNoExtension

In this case it would show nothing or if possible "Blank"

Comment: Why are you using a regex instead of `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\.[^.]+$
```

**Sample Usage**

```
if ($filename -cmatch '\.[^.]+$') {
    $extension = $matches[0]
}
```

**Explanation**

- `\.` matches a dot
- `[^.]+` matches chars that are not a dot
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: You arrived first ! :( Anyway nice answer

Comment: This is for a creating a new object in an hash table so using an IF statement doesn't flow well, I should of put that in the post sorry.

Comment: @user3862909 My focus is on giving you the right regex, I trust you to write the code you need. :) The code sample is just to show an example of using the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without using a regex.  Use `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($fileName)`.

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension("README.md")
  returns .md

[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension("README")
  returns nothing
```

[You can find more info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I used this and I got the same output at what I was using, Although yours looks more aesthetic so I will be using that for now =)